# Proxy server in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am doing performance testing on jsf application using jmeter. I went through this link(http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) and followed the steps whatever mentioned. I have changed the proxy server setting also but still i am not able to record the scenarios. I am facing problem with the proxy server.

Comment: More detail might help.  What other clues do you observe?  Any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

There are several common mistakes in regards to proxy server configuration like:

- If application under test lives on the same host with JMeter it is necessary to remove `localhost, 127.0.0.1` from "No proxy for" input in your browser proxy configuration window
- If your application uses HTTPS - you need to check `Use this proxy for all protocols` box

[image: Firefox Proxy Configuration]

- If you're running JMeter from behind the corporate proxy you need to pass its details via command line arguments

> ```
>     -H, --proxyHost <argument>
>             Set a proxy server for JMeter to use
>     -P, --proxyPort <argument>
>             Set proxy server port for JMeter to use
>     -N, --nonProxyHosts <argument>
>             Set nonproxy host list (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
>     -u, --username <argument>
>             Set username for proxy server that JMeter is to use
>     -a, --password <argument>
>             Set password for proxy server that JMeter is to use
> ```

By the way, there is an easier way of recording JMeter test without needing to worry about proxies, SSL certificates, adding a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to test plan, etc.

Check out [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/BlazeMeter?hl=en) which allows to record a JMeter test right from Google Chrome browser.